# Can not set the resolution manually

Tags: resolution

I use ubuntu 13.04 and I have a 23-inch LCD and max resolution I can get is 1024×768

I am trying to set resolution to 1280×720. I wrote:

```
cvt 1280 720 60 then
xrandr --newmode 1280x720 74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
then
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x720
then
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x720
```

http://webconverger.org/display/
and it works but when restart or shutdown this message appears:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Click on the image to open a full-resolution version.</sup>

Then I deleted

```
 config/monitors.xml
cp ~/.config/monitors.xml monitors.xml.bad
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

and the message disappeared. I tried all these steps several times and I faced the same problem.